# Wrong music player when connecting to car after Android update

Tags: updates, music-player, default-applications, bluetooth-audio

I have a Huawei P10 and I use BlackPlayer for playing music. When I start my car and my bluetooth is active my car (Volvo V40) automatically connects to my phone and starts playing music.

Yesterday I did an update of my phone, now my EMUI and Android versions are both 8.0.0, and since that update when my car and phone connect, my phone starts playing music with the standard build in music player. Before the update it used the (installed by me) BlackPlayer.

When I go to my settings and look at the standard selected app to play music it shows that BlackPlayer is still the default to use app. How can I make BlackPlayer start to play again when I connect to my car?

I have a Huawei P10 model VTR-L09 with EMUI and Android version 8.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some recent updates the problem is gone